# Retrieve site collection quota and used storage from REST or JSOM

Tags: 2013, rest, client-object-model, quota

Is there a way to retrieve the amount of storage used and the quota limit for the Site Collection using the JSOM client or the REST web services?

Comment: I'm searching for the same thing but in SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The REST query

```
https://<siteUrl>/_api/site/usage
```

will return the following:

```
{
    "d": {
        "Usage": {
            "__metadata": {
                "type": "SP.UsageInfo"
            },
            "Bandwidth": "0",
            "DiscussionStorage": "0",
            "Hits": "0",
            "Storage": "354721461",
            "StoragePercentageUsed": 0.0330360104329884,
            "Visits": "0"
        }
    }
}
```

Storage will give us "Storage Used"(in Bytes) not the "Total Storage" you can calculate the amount of storage used based on `Storage` and `StoragePercentageUsed`

Comment: This only gets the site collection size. On all subsites it returns the same number... any idea how we can get the size of each subsite?

Comment: how can i get the "Maximum storage allowed "

Comment: I get permission denied. I am trying to get data for a site i belong to

Answer (score 7):

### How to access information about site collection usage via CSOM

[SP.UsageInfo object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245404.aspx) provides fields that are used to access information about site collection usage.

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var site = context.get_site();
context.load(site,'Usage');  
context.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {

        var siteUsageInfo = site.get_usage();                   
        console.log(siteUsageInfo.get_storage());          
        console.log(siteUsageInfo.get_storagePercentageUsed());             
    },
    function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$cred = Get-Credential

$adminSiteURL = "spo admin url here"   
Connect-SPOService -Url $adminSiteURL -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop

$tenant = Get-SPOTenant -ErrorAction Stop   

$siteCollections = Get-SPOSite -Limit All -ErrorAction Stop 

$allocated = [math]::Round(($tenant.StorageQuota / 1024 / 1024), 2)

$used = [math]::Round((($siteCollections.StorageUsageCurrent | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum / 1024 / 1024), 2)

$data = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Allocated = $allocated
        Used      = $used
        PercentUsed = [math]::Round((($used / $allocated) * 100), 2)
}   

$data  | OGV
```

Comment: Could you please add more details to describe your script, BTW, the OP was asking about JSOM or REST API solution!